# "Last modified" time in the title or statusline

Tags: vim, windows-xp, cmd

What would be the easiest way to display the *last modified* time of a file (the time at which the file was saved last) in the title or in the statusline?

I have a few ideas, but they all require parsing the *dir* (oh, I forgot to mention, ... I'm using Windows XP and cmd) *command output*. Any better solutions? Or just ideas on what would be the shortest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
:set title titlestring=%{strftime('%c',getftime(expand('%')))}
```